# Inverse Laplace Transform?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

How would you take the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{3p}{(p^2 + 4)^2} $

I attempted to split it as $\frac{3p}{p^2 + 4} $ x $\frac{1}{p^2 + 4} $

Then i know $\frac{3p}{p^2 + 4} $ has laplace tranform $ 3cos(2t) $ and $\frac{1}{p^2 + 4} $ has laplace transform $\frac{1}{2}sin(2t)$

So via convolution theorem the function i want is:

$$\frac{3}{2} \int_{0}^{t} sin(2s)cos(2(t-s)) \,  ds$$

Which im not too sure how to integrate?

Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_both_sine_and_cosine

Comment: Integrals like this can be made simpler by use of the cosine and sine addition/subtraction formulas

Answer (score 2):

> "Or is there a simpler way?"

HINT:

$$\frac{d}{dp}\left( \frac{-3/2}{p^2+4}\right)=\frac{3p}{(p^2+4)^2}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark